# Plotly: Secondary y-axis causes empty space on the right

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

I'm working on a plotly dash chart with lots of data that runs on ultra high res. On adding the second y-axis, I discovered, that an empty space appears on the right of the chart inside of the plotly svg component. That empty space vanishes when I turn off the second axis. It can be seen very well, when the chart is maximized over the entire screen.

As a showcase I used an example from the plotly documentation:

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Create figure with secondary y-axis
fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

# Add traces
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[40, 50, 60], name="yaxis data"),
    secondary_y=False,
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=[2, 3, 4], y=[4, 5, 6], name="yaxis2 data"),
    secondary_y=True,
)

# Add figure title
fig.update_layout(
    title="Right margin",
    showlegend=False
)

# Set x-axis title
fig.update_xaxes(title_text="xaxis title")

# Set y-axes titles
fig.update_yaxes(title_text="<b>primary</b> yaxis title", secondary_y=False)
fig.update_yaxes(title_text="<b>secondary</b> yaxis title", secondary_y=True)

fig.show()
```

It yields the following chart, not being centered any more:

[empty_space_on_the_right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Pb4p.png)

How can I get rid of that empty space?

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be something wrong when calculating the horizontal sizes when the `secondary_y` is included. This can be fixed changing the margin passed via `specs`:

```
fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True,"r":-0.06}]])
```

In this case, you can resize, and both sides keep the same distance to the borders.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the margins in `fig.update_layout()`. I set the right margin to 0.

You can also adjust the top, bottom and left margins.
e.g.
`margin = dict(l=50, r=50, b=50, t=50)`

```
# Add figure title
fig.update_layout(
    title="Right margin",
    showlegend=False,
    margin=dict(r=0)
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that improves the chart. But still, if you do that, remove the axis titles and look at the chart at a width of 1900 and a width of 600, you will discover that in one case the left axis has a bigger distance to the border than the right and vice versa in the other case. There is something in there on the right border that scales with the chart size. Setting the margin relative to the chart size is not possible though ...